# RDC via Smartphone

Tags: remote-desktop, smartphone

Is there any way to connect to RDC with help of smarphone? Can it be used for support and developer purposes? Share your experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your smartphone has a terminal services client, yes. my HTC G1 has one. im sure any pocket pc/windows mobile smartphone would have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

The HTC HD2 has a great client app, but I don't know how well you'd cope on (much) smaller screens, if it will even run on the device.